# Use VBA for generating Auto reference for a transaction

Tags: vba, excel

I am  trying to write a code to generate auto transaction reference as well as assigning it to the employee ,could any one help me to find the equation for making it incremental as for example reference is `COMP100015/12/2015` , the next would be `COMP100115/12/2015`

Code I use:

```
Sub LeftArrow2_Click()
 Dim RowCount As Long

 Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
  With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

  .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Environ("username")
  .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = "COMP" & Date
  .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")

End With

End Sub
```

Result of this code:

```
reference   Officer                Date 
COMP15/12/2015  aselhayani  15/12/2015 18:10:18
COMP15/12/2015  aselhayani  15/12/2015 18:10:19
```

Comment: Do you want it to be higher by 1 comparing to previous row? Or do you want to make a loop with certain number of records?

Comment: Do you want the 10000,10001... to reset each day or just keep incrementing regardless of the date?

Comment: @ScottCraner - Minor point, but he's actually looking for 4 decimal places.  It looks like 5 because of the way there is no space before the date.

Comment: @Demetri you are correct.  The question still stands, just with 1000,1001...

Comment: I want it incrementing regardless the date Thanks Scott Craner ,

Comment: @ScottCraner I WANT IT just TO keep incrementing regardless of the date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would adjust the code like so:

```
Sub LeftArrow2_Click()

Dim RowCount As Long
Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range, i As Long

RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")

    .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Environ("username")
    ' Get the next index based on the prior index, if it existed, adding one to it.
    On Error Resume Next: i = Val(Mid(.Offset(RowCount - 1, 0).Value, 5, 4)) + 1: On Error GoTo 0
    ' Put the index in, formatted to 4 zeroes.
    .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = "COMP" & Format(i, "0000") & Date
    .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi demetri can u help me in my other question

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you need transaction reference in column 1, try this:

```
Sub LeftArrow2_Click()
 Dim RowCount As Long

 Dim cell As Range, Rng As Range

 RowCount = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

 With Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
     .Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Environ("username")
     .Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = "COMP" & CInt(Mid(.Offset(RowCount-1, 0).Value, 5, 4)) + 1 & Date
     .Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
 End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Well done - does what my solution does but better, and more compact.

Comment: The only thing I might add is the format to 4 zeroes.

Comment: @Demetri Infact your answer is better, since it includes error checking that  can occur when filling first row. and it also format for 4 digit number